# Detect URL connection attempt by desktop application

Tags: proxy, firewall

A user is using Autodesk Project Vasari 2, which provides training videos.  The videos are blocked by the corporate firewall.

Is there a method I can use to find out what URLs the application is trying to load?  I can then pass this information on to the network admin to unblock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Pick a network interface and start capturing the network traffic.
At first log level shows everything, but you could filter out the unnecessary parts.
For starters, check out DNS requests, if that fails (they could be cached), check the TCP and UDP connections.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html). You can change the settings to show various connection types, or opt for URL or resolved name.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against installing WireShark as that's probably against company policy.

Your system admin should be able to look at the proxy/firewall logs to find the blocked request. He/She would need your IP address and the time of the request to narrow down the search.